# Difference between hero and fluid templates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in Bootstrap and I'm about to choose a template for my project, but I'm unable to see the difference between:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html

and the fluid version:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

I would like a template that displays well in desktop and mobile browsers, I've tested those  on iOS devices and they look the same (except for the sidebar on the fluid, of course).

In my humble opinion both examples miss a call to an image to illustrate better the differences.

Comment: I've found it, my desktop is >1200px wide so the difference between both templates cannot be noticed. I just enlarged the browser window and saw it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fluid expands to the full width of the browser, the hero.html does not. The fluid would be good for an app, where as the hero version would be good for a brochure site.

Comment: Ok but how can I experience the difference?

If I look at them from my desktop browser (Chrome on OS X) they look the same and behave the same way. I am missing something, for sure.

Thanks anyway.